# Common xsd schema for multiple xmls

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation, xmlschema

I want to build a common xsd schema file to validate the below 3 format xmls and xsd to validate only the top 2 levels. Please let know if it's possible.

```
<product:Data>
    <applicaiton>
        <!-- I dont want to validate the below elements -->
        <appField1>value1</appField1>
        <appField2>value2</appField2>
    </application> 
</production:Data>

<product:Data>
    <user>
        <!-- I dont want to validate the below elements -->
        <userField1>val1</userField1>
        <userField2>val2</userField2>
    </user>  
</product:Data>

<product:Data>
     <price>
        <!-- I dont want to validate the below elements -->
        <priceField1>valu1</priceField1>
        <priceField11>valu11</priceField11>
     </price> 
</product:Data>
```

Comment: Product data must have exactly one of application, user, or price? What XSD have you tried so far? Would you post it?

Comment: Which version of XSD do you use?

Comment: yes, it will be one for application, user and price. I didn't come up with XSD so far.

Comment: Use `xs:choice` for the contents of the `product:Data` element. Then `xs:any` for the elements you don't want to specify.